# Why is a special file used in Android to store installation id instead of SharedPreferences?

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out the best way to store my application key and other application specific data. Android uses a file to do it - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

I found that using SharedPreferences is faster and more efficient. Why does Android use a dedicated file just to store the installation ID instead of using preferences? Both require the application context, so that is not a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess so that the UUID is persisted across installations if the phone is not factory-reset.

An applications `SharedPreferences` are removed when that application is uninstalled. So if a user uninstalled/re-installed and the ID was stored in `SharedPreferences` then the ID would be different after the re-installation.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. As per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal "You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed"

Comment: Aah, yes I guess it depends on where you save them.

Comment: Clear Data button in the App info screen can also be used to clear SharedPreferences